# How can I Improve ping parameters to get consistent response vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ping

I'm having an issue with an inconsistent response on some of the ip's on my network. Basically I am getting a success or failure randomly every time I ping it however if I ping from the windows command line it is successful every time... The code I'm using to ping is as follows:

```
    Dim myping As Ping = New Ping
    Dim pingreply As PingReply
    Dim host As String = "x.x.x.x"
    Dim Timeout = 1000
    Dim PacketSize = 32
    Dim data As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To PacketSize
        data = String.Concat(data, "a")
    Next

    Dim buffer() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

    Try
        pingreply = myping.Send(host, Timeout, buffer)

        If pingreply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
            MsgBox("Success")
        Else
            MsgBox("Failure")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

It might also be useful to know that I am accessing the network through a VPN but that doesn't explain why the command line ping is successful.

Is there any way that I can adjust the parameters to get a consistent response? I'd like to avoid slowing down the pinging time significantly as there are many ip's to ping.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bewere the Windows' `ping.exe` gives it a 5 seconds timeout, so yeah, it may suceed where yours fail if the latency is too high though thats probably not the case. Also, you are ommiting the `PingOptions` parameter that might carry important information to the ping packet behaviour.

Try again with:

```
Dim options as PingOptions = new PingOptions
options.DontFragment = true

(...)

pingreply = myping.Send(host, Timeout, buffer, options)
```

Comment: Looks like that did the trick! I haven't done a lot of testing but on first glance it looks good. I'm getting a consistent response now. Thanks for the help!